# Were the Buddha's earliest followers bhikkhus?

Tags: the-buddha, terminology, early-buddhism, bhikkhu

What is the proper name for the Buddha's earliest followers such as [Ananda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ananda) and [Sariputta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sariputta) - the ones that followed the Buddha during his lifetime. Would the term be bhikkhu and  bhikkhuni or does this only apply to settled monastics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest records we have refer to Ānanda in many ways. But bhikkhu is one of them. For example in the ***Mahāpadāna Sutta*** we find

> *Mayhaṃ, bhikkhave, etarahi ānando nāma bhikkhu upaṭṭhāko ahosi aggupaṭṭhāko*.
>   A bhikkhu called Ānanda, monks, was our servant, the best of servants.

Similarly in the ***Kalyaṇamitta Sutta*** (SN i.87)

> Atha kho, mahārāja, ānando bhikkhu yenāhaṃ tenupasaṅkami
>   Then, your Majesty, I approached the bhikkhu Ānanda...

However he is frequently referred to as *āyasmā ānando* roughly Elder Ānanda. His ordination as a bhikkhu was probably fairly conventional. It's not recounted in full. But at least twice his preceptor (upajjhāya) is mentioned, e.g.

> Tena kho pana samayena āyasmato ānandassa upajjhāyo āyasmā belaṭṭhasīso araññe viharati.  (Vin 4.86)
>   At that time Belaṭṭhaṣīso, the preceptor of Ānanda, was living in the wilderness.

Sāriputta's ordination was a bit less convention. He was converted by Assaji and already a stream-entrant when he met the Buddha. Curiously I cannot find any evidence of Sāriputta being called a bhikkhu in Pāḷi.

In some discourses that seem to be early the Buddha ordains men by saying *ehi bhikkhu* "come monk", but this was soon replaced by the more formal two stage ordination process.

On the whole I think *bhikkhu* and *bhikkhunī* are fine. They really refer to a lifestyle rather than being an ecclesiastical title.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4

- Bhikkhu - Male monk
- Bhikkhuni - Female nun
- Upasaka - Lay male follower
- Upasika - Lay female follower

Also note that in the Suttas all of the above are referred as Bhikkhus in addressing.

Answer (score 1):

In [Maha-parinibbana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html), for example, they're referred to as "bhikkhus" and "Venerable".

In [this translation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.5-6.than.html#chap5) it's "monks" and "Venerable".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu) says that,

> Bhikkhu literally means "beggar" or "one who lives by alms".

The 'ordained' monastics and the Vinaya existed (were created) during the Buddha's lifetime.